# Storing Process names in an Array in iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
     for (i = 0; i < nprocs;  i++) {

            NSString *processName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",procs[i].kp_proc.p_comm];

            [pid addObject:processName];
            NSLog(@"name: %@", pid[i] );

}
```

The result I am getting is null all the time..

Comment: nprocs what is that ? nd explain you question in brief description.

Comment: Yes, please post the code where you invoke sysctl.